# Match String only if preceding character is not there

Tags: regex

I want to completely discard a match if it begins with the letter `C`.

This is an example text, each line is a separate example:

```
C4526913CA57248560A562492460C
A000008002A20839256662C
C370694CA102000979A68008192429291C
```

The regex I am using is

```
[cC]?([0-9*dD]){5,}[cC]
```

Match :

```
1: C4526913C
2: 562492460C
3: 20839256662C
4: C370694C
5: 68008192429291C
```

but I don't want to match the ones that start with `C`, and I have tried these

```
(?!^[cC])[cC]?([0-9*dD]){5,}[cC]
(?![cC].*[cC])([cC]?([0-9*dD]){5,}[cC])
```

Which adds a negative look ahead but instead it matches everything except the starting `C` instead of discarding the whole match. Like so:

```
C4526913C -> 4526913C
```

How can I achieve this with just regular expressions?

Comment: `(?<![cC0-9*dD])([0-9*dD]){5,}[cC]`

Comment: This is It! Thank you @jhnc, I am okay with regex but the negative lookbehind didn't work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep.

As there is a single character class in the group `([0-9*dD]){5,}` you can omit the group and just repeat the character class.

Note that `[0-9*dD]` matches a digit 0-9 or `*` or `d` or `D` but only the digits are in the example data to match.

```
[cC][0-9*dD]{5,}[cC]|([0-9*dD]{5,}[cC])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbBDvk/1)

For the example data (without `D` `d` and `*`) you could also use a lookbehind if that is supported:

```
(?<![cC0-9])[0-9]{5,}[cC]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHqUFm/1)

Comment: The `*`, `d`, and `D` could occur but I didn't have any examples of it. Lookbehind is supported in node so I am using that. Thank you.

Comment: @jhnc  That is why you match the ones that you don't want, and capture what you want to keep in group 1.